# UITableView is lagging a cell containing a UITextView is displayed the first time

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, scroll, uitextview

I'm running into issues with a UITableView that lags while scrolling when specific cells will move to superview.

I've written my own IPFormKit for an easy way to create beautiful input forms with different kind of inputViews without having to re-code everything manually for each form field / cell.

I've got a UITableViewController that initializes my IPFormKit and its fields. 
The `- (UITableViewCell *) cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath;` loads the dequeued custom cells (called IPFormTableViewCell) and assigns the IPFormField to each cell.

The custom UITableViewCell (IPFormTableViewCell) creates all (possibly) required inputViews (UITextField, UITextView, CustomUILabel) with a CGRectZero on initialization.

The matching `inputView` depending on the IPFormField's type (that was already inited as an iVar of the cell) is resized and added as a subview to the `cell.contentView` within.

```m
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath
```

For UITextField and CustomUILabel this works flawlessly, but **when the inputView is a UIText*View*, the scrolling of the UITableView lags (slightly) noticable when this cell will be displayed for the first time.**

When the cell will be displayed again later after scrolling a bit (even if the cell was reused and thus the UITextView removed and readded), there is *no* lag and scrolling is super smooth for those cells.

I'm running out of ideas what the reason for this lag could be.
Any idea is appreciated.

PS: The lag is noticable on both, iPhone 4 and iPhone 4S and is of almost exactly the same duration (so it should not be CPU related)

`UITableViewController.m`:

**- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath**

```m
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"IPFormFieldCell";

    // Get Form Field for indexPath
    IPFormField *formField = [self.form fieldAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    IPTableViewCell *cell = (IPTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[IPTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.backgroundView = nil;
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = nil;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    [cell assignFormField:formField];

    return cell;
}
```

`IPFormTableViewCell.m`:

**- (void) assignFormField:(IPFormField *)field:**

```m
- (void) assignFormField:(IPFormField *)field {
    if (formField != nil) {
        formField.inputView = nil; // unlink old field
    }

    self.formField = field;

    // Change Field Label
    [fieldLabel setText:[field label]];

    // Add an Input View to the Field
    UIView *labelView = nil;
    UIView *inputView = nil;

    switch (formField.type) {
        case IPFormFieldTypeTextField:
        {
            labelView = fieldLabel;

            UITextField *textField = inputTextField;
            textField.delegate = (IPFormTextField *)formField;
            textField.inputAccessoryView = [formField.form inputAccessoryView];
            textField.placeholder = [self.formField stringFromValue:self.formField.defaultValue];
            textField.keyboardType = [(IPFormTextField *)formField keyboardType];

            if (self.formField.value == nil || [[self.formField stringFromValue:self.formField.value] isEqualToString:[self.formField stringFromValue:self.formField.defaultValue]]) {
                textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = YES;
            } else {
                textField.text = [self.formField stringFromValue:self.formField.value];
                textField.clearsOnBeginEditing = NO;
            }

            inputView = textField;
            break;
        }

        case IPFormFieldTypeTextArea:
        {            
            UITextView *textView = inputTextView;
            textView.delegate = (IPFormTextArea *)formField;
            textView.inputAccessoryView = [formField.form inputAccessoryView];

            if (self.formField.value == nil || ![[self.formField stringFromValue:self.formField.value] length] > 0) {
                textView.text = [self.formField stringFromValue:self.formField.defaultValue];
            } else {
                textView.text = [self.formField stringFromValue:self.formField.value];
            }

            inputView = textView;
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }

    self.leftItem = labelView;
    self.rightItem = inputView;

    if (leftItem != nil) {
        [self.contentView addSubview:leftItem];
    }

    if (rightItem != nil) {
        [self.contentView addSubview:rightItem];
    }

    formField.inputView = rightItem;
}
```

Comment: Provide some more code, maybe whole `cellForRowAtIndexpath`, so that we could determine the problem. My guess, the problem here is related to your custom controls.

Comment: I've added the source code, but the `- (void) assignFormField:` method gets called every time a cell is requested from the tableView, so this would not explain, why it is lagging only when a cell becomes visible the first time. Notice that it won't lag when a cell becomes visible a second time, even if the cell has been reused (so the previous inputView - the UITextView had been removed from superview) in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` of my dataSource made use of a field's property, that was set as `@property (nonatomic, copy)` instead of `@property (nonatomic, readonly)`.

Now that I've fixed it, the scrolling isn't lagging anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As I guessed, your problem here is with your custom controls. Yes, you are reusing the cell, but this doesn't give anything in your case, as every time you request for the cell, you are creating new custom control for each cell. My advise, you can create and keep your custom controls as an instance variables, and when required return them without many `if-else`s, or, you could create custom cells for your two cases, and keep them dequeued with different cell identifiers and reuse them. Good Luck!

Comment: I _am_ storing the inputViews (UITextView, UITextField, CustomUILabel) in instance variables. They are allocated and inited with a CGRectZero on UITableViewCell's init. Within the assignFormField: method, I just assign the form Field as delegate and set inputAccessoryView and the text value.